# How do I undo the changes I made to use FTPS on windows 2016 server

Tags: windows-server-2016, ftps

I set up FTPS requiring client certificates on an internal server, for some testing.  Now after undoing those changes (I thought), the FTP site is still demanding SSL.

```
220 Microsoft FTP Service
200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
User (devtestw16iv01.gtsoftware.com:(none)): lreinitz
534 Policy requires SSL.
Login failed.
ftp>
```

I have uninstalled the FTP extensions and changed the applicationHost.config file to what I believe to be it's original state.

```
            <site name="FTP" id="2">
            <application path="/">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\ftproot" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="ftp" bindingInformation="*:21:" />
            </bindings>
            <ftpServer>
                <security>
                    <authentication>
                        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                        <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
                    </authentication>
                </security>
            </ftpServer>
        </site>
```

I have no idea how to proceed from here.  I have compared it to a working site and can find no differences in the applicationHost.config file.

Answer (score 0):

When I added the following line to the security element in the sample above it started working.

```
<ssl serverCertStoreName="MY" ssl128="false" controlChannelPolicy="SslAllow" dataChannelPolicy="SslAllow" />
```

I have no idea why this line is required, it was not in the original applicationHost.config